# DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': on a clean HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for my bad english, because it's not my native language. And I am a beginner in javascript/jquery.

So, I have a clear HTML-document with a link to jquery library

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But Chrome's console displays an error

> Exception: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector. at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:11282 at ja (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:7443)... and so on

Does anyone know the reason for this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Is that all that's in the page? You're not adding any other JS code? I'm unable to replicate the error from what you've shown: https://jsfiddle.net/y5b31x3g/

Comment: I had some code on the page, and the console threw an exception. I deleted all the jquery code, but I continued to receive exception. But when I deleted a link to jquery's library the exception disappeared

Comment: Did you somehow checked the "Pause on caught exceptions" option in the DevTools' "Source" panel ? This exception is part of a test jquery does perform, and is most probably intended, and it shouldn't fire otherwise, since it wrapped in a try-catch block.

Comment: That is the answer I am looking for! Thank you!